# How to fix color cells in my pixel art maker that are black?

Tags: javascript, css, background-color

I am working on a pixel art maker for my studies, and I have one problem remaining.

I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code, cells are colored in black even if a color is selected with a color picker. What did I miss ? I am almost new to JS.

```js
// Select color
var chooseColor = document.getElementById('colorPicker').value;
// Select size  
var size = document.getElementById('sizePicker');
var height = document.getElementById('inputHeight').value;
var width = document.getElementById('inputWidth').value;



var canvas = document.getElementById("pixelCanvas");

size.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  var height = document.getElementById('inputHeight').value;
  var width = document.getElementById('inputWidth').value;
  makeGrid(height, width);
});



function makeGrid(height, width) {
  var height = document.getElementById('inputHeight').value;
  var width = document.getElementById('inputWidth').value;
  canvas.innerHTML = null;
  for (var m = 0; m < height; m++) {
    var row = canvas.insertRow(m);
    for (var n = 0; n < width; n++) {
      var column = row.insertCell(n);
      column.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var color = chooseColor;
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = color;
      })
    }
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(203, 224, 236, 0.2);
  font-family: Baskerville;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  margin: 0.2em;
  border-style: outset;
  border-color: rgb(42, 42, 143);
}

h2 {
  margin: 1em 0 0.25em;
}

h2:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  padding: 35px;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

tr {
  height: 25px;
}

td {
  width: 25px;
}

input[type=number] {
  width: 6em;
}

input[type=submit]:active {
  background-color: rgba(41, 28, 185, 0.5);
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baskerville" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <h1>Pixel Art Maker</h1>

  <h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
  <form id="sizePicker" onsubmit="makeGrid(event)">
    Grid Height:
    <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1"> Grid Width:
    <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="1">
    <input type="submit" value="submit/erase">
  </form>

  <h2>Pick Your Color</h2>
  <input type="color" id="colorPicker">

  <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
  <table id="pixelCanvas"></table>
</body>
```

I do not get any error message, just cells colored in black. Thanks in advance for your help/advice :)

Comment: Why are you using a table at all, not a real `<canvas>`?

Comment: @Bergi arguably that sounds like a legit exercise for "studies" and to get their hand on *basic* js script with *basic* DOM manipulation and *basic* event handling. Sure doing it with a canvas is doable, but just the code to check in which cell they are clicking would be more complex than all they got right now.

Comment: Yes, we have only studied basic stuff, and not the "real canvas" as you say, and we have specific coding requirements; thank you for you interest :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the value of your input on top of your code " on run time ", so only the initial value is used.

```
var chooseColor = document.getElementById('colorPicker').value;
```

You just need to move it inside your function `makeGrid`.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x2of0kL7/3/)

Comment: In the click event handler would probably even be better (I guess they don't want to do monochrome pixel art)

Comment: Fiat lux ! I was close, but could not get to find where the problem was. When I saw the cells colored, I felt really happy ! Great, thanks a lot :)